# Excel 'If' formula how to check if value is less than x but more than y?

Tags: excel

I have a Excel If formula which I'm having trouble with.

```
=IF(OR(C7<9.97, D7<9.97, E7<9.97, F7<9.97), "NG", IF(OR(C7>10.03, D7>10.03, E7>10.03, F7>10.03), "NG", IF(OR(C7=0, D7=0, E7=0, F7 = 0), "N/A",  "OK")))
```

For those having trouble following *(I don't blame you...)* the formula is divided into 4 steps.

1) If values in cell C7, D7, E7 & F7 is less than 9.97, this cell will generate NG.

2) If values in cell C7, D7, E7 & F7 is more than 10.03, this cell will generate NG as well.

3) If values in cell C7, D7, E7 & F7 equals 0, this cell will generate N\A.

4) If none of the above conditions are met, this cell will generate OK.

So far all of them are working fine, except 3). Since 1) covers all values lower than 9.97, that includes 0 as well & defaults to NG which is not what I want.

In my head I'm planning to change the IF statement for 1) so that it will check for values less than 9.97 but not equal 0, but I'm not quite sure how to tackle it. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unite the first two conditions like this:

```
=IF(OR(C7<9.97, D7<9.97, E7<9.97, F7<9.97, C7>10.03, D7>10.03,E7>10.03, F7>10.03), "NG", 
 IF(OR(C7=0, D7=0, E7=0, F7 = 0), "N/A",  "OK")))
```

Then change the place of the conditions like this, so you check for `=0` first:

```
=IF(OR(C7=0, D7=0, E7=0, F7 = 0), "N/A", 
 IF(OR(C7<9.97, D7<9.97, E7<9.97, F7<9.97, C7>10.03, D7>10.03,E7>10.03, F7>10.03),
"NG", "OK")))
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a couple of minutes. I don't think the "OK" value will ever be returned - a number will always fall into one of those categories.  Should it show NG on negative numbers as well?

Comment: the values are data from measuring equipment. I don't think its very likely I'll get negative value, so no need. thanks.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - `10.00` would be `OK`.

Comment: @Vityata Yep you're correct - anything between 9.97 & 10.03. Don't think my brain's awake yet.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - I know this feeling :)

Answer (score 1):

Just as a footnote, since the cells are in a continuous range, you could shorten it by using countif:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C7:F7,0),"N/A",IF(COUNTIF(C7:F7,"<9.97")+COUNTIF(C7:F7,">10.03"),"NG","OK"))
```